# Run timer exactly every second with systemd

Tags: devops, systemd

How to run some service exactly every second? Overlapping allowed.

Here is my timer unit for systemd:

```
[Unit]
Description=Send jobs every second

[Timer]
OnBootSec=1min
OnUnitActiveSec=1s
Unit=app.jobs-send.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But `app.jobs-send.service` service doesn't executed every second:

```
May 07 17:57:38 app.deployer.org systemd[1]: Started Send jobs to queue.
May 07 17:57:48 app.deployer.org systemd[1]: Starting Send jobs to queue...
May 07 17:57:48 app.deployer.org systemd[1]: Started Send jobs to queue.
May 07 17:57:58 app.deployer.org systemd[1]: Starting Send jobs to queue...
May 07 17:57:58 app.deployer.org systemd[1]: Started Send jobs to queue.
May 07 17:58:08 app.deployer.org systemd[1]: Starting Send jobs to queue...
May 07 17:58:08 app.deployer.org systemd[1]: Started Send jobs to queue.
```

There is a gap about 17:57:58 - 17:57:48 = 10 seconds.

How to exec task every second?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As documented in [man systemd.time](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html), the accuracy of `OnUnitActiveSec=` is subject to the `AccuracySec=` setting, also documented there. Set to `AccuracySec=1us` for best resolution.